# Использование rendertexture в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь получать фотки через instagram Api, обработать как мне надо и отображать их в виде некоторого слайдшоу.

Авторизуюсь, получаю данные по json, получаю оттуда ссылки на фото, стягиваю фото, стягиваю описание, число лайков и тд, далее мне необходимо подставить их в специальный префаб(на сцене) на который смотрит отдельно созданная для этого камера с RenderTexture, сохранить отрендеренное этой камерой в спрайт и уже этот спрайт использовать в слайд шоу. Делается это с целью что бы не только картинка но и текстовые данные тоже запеклись в спрайт что бы его потом анимировать с такими эффектами как мне надо как цельную картинку.

Проблемы начались на этапе тестирования на разных девайсах, на Nexus5 все работает прекрасно, на (например) Acer Icona Tab куча глитча и ничего адекватного. Пример того как это выглядит на девайсе где возникают проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если при этом я в Unity выставляю `Edit - Graphics Emulation - OpenGL ES 2.0` то такой же удел постигает и Nexus5, попытки выставлять при запекании текстуры в рантайм  у Texture2D значения генерации mipmap в False не помогли. Код "запекания" следующий.

```
private IEnumerator BakeData(RenderTexture rt, Action<List<Sprite>> callback)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _fs.Photos.Count; i++)
            {
                _fs.Photos[i].SetPhotoData(page, FeedViewConfig.Instance._modeEnum);
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                var txt2d = new Texture2D(rt.width, rt.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32,  false,false);
                BakeCamera.targetTexture = rt;
                BakeCamera.Render();
                RenderTexture.active = rt;
                txt2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0, true);
                txt2d.Apply();
                var photoWidth = backCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
                var photoHeight = photoWidth * 1.25f;
                var sprite = Sprite.Create(txt2d, new Rect(0, (txt2d.height - photoHeight) / 2, txt2d.width, photoHeight), Vector2.zero);
                yield return sprite;
                _pageSprites.Add(sprite);
            }
            BakeCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            callback(_pageSprites);
        }
```

где `rt` это `RenderTexture`
В общем выслушаю любые варианты и попробую их. Уже голову сломал.

Comment: А отображение 'голых' фото без излишков на Icona Tab нормально отрисовывается?

Comment: если честно не знаю, по причине отсутствия возможности сделать это сейчас. Подозреваю что в таком случае все будет нормально ибо в случае с "голым" фото мы просто сохраняем фото по ссылке без участия RenderTexture. Могу поставить режим эмуляции Open Gl Es2.0 и попробовать сохранить голые фото на nexus5

Comment: Если дело не в фото, то можно пробовать создать анимацию за счет композиции GUI элементов, чтобы не связоваться с RenderTexture.

Comment: @Shakra там различные анимации, например книжное листание фото, различные вариации проявления с фэйдом и тд и тп. Под каждый эффект делать анимацию, ну мягко говоря не самая удачная идея. Хотелось бы разобраться откуда ноги растут все таки ))

Comment: Могу посоветовать только поиграть с настройками вторичной камеры и посмотреть как поведется себя приложение на глючном телефоне. Как  второй вариант попробовать, для теста, отказаться от вторичной камеры и использовать для запекания первичную камеру.

Comment: @Shakra да вот уже поигрался, есть подозрение что именно с этим дело и было (точнее с Clear Flags) отправил билд потестить, жду результат.